Trying to navigate to another gui form when a button is clicked
I want another GUI form that has its own frame and is in another class, to open when a button is clicked.
This is button actionListener . i tried setting its visibilities but its not working:
        createButton.addActionListener( e -> {
            Create.frame.setVisible(true);

        });

I want this class's GUI to open when i click the buttton above:
import javax.swing.*;

public class Create {

     static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Create");
    private JTextField textName;
    private JTextField textNumber;
    private JTextField textAddress;
    private JButton createButton;
    private JPanel Main;
    private JButton contactsButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame.setContentPane(new Create().Main);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(500, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Utils.Connect();
    }
    public Create(){



        createButton.addActionListener( e ->{
            String name = textName.getText();
            String phone = textNumber.getText();
            String address = textAddress.getText();

            try {
                Utils.preStmt = Utils.connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO contactsdb (name, phone_Number, address) VALUES (?,?,?) ");
                Utils.preStmt.setString(1, name);
                Utils.preStmt.setString(2, phone);
                Utils.preStmt.setString(3, address);

                Utils.preStmt.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Contact created successfully");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Contact created successfully");
                textName.setText("");
                textNumber.setText("");
                textAddress.setText("");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });

        contactsButton.addActionListener( e -> {
            new Create();
        });
    }
}


The code in your question is not a [mcve] because it does not compile since it is missing class Utils. In any case, I don't think the JDBC code is relevant to your problem. When I remove the Utils references from the code, I get NullPointerException when I run the code since createButton is null. I suggest that you read [ask] and also visit this Swing tutorial.

Don't use static variables. If you want to display an new form, then you should have a class named something like "ContactForm". In the ActionListener of your button you would then invoke code like " new ContactForm()". In the constructor of your ContactForm class you would create the frame and add components to the frame and make the frame visible. So basically the code in the main() method would be moved to the constructor of the class.
